# how to know whether the media file is supported, android

Tags: android, compatibility, android-videoview

I have a video file in SD card. I want to check whether that file is supported or not if not supported then i have to do some specific action. I have read the following document on supporting media file format in android. But Programmatic How to know whether the file is supported by my android device.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting this question after I found it a few weeks ago unanswered....

You can try to play it in a VideoView...

```
videoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            // An error occured trying to play the file, do something else.
        }
});
```

This is not a way to "just check a file if it is supported" but you can use this to play the file and do something else if it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late answer but maybe someone will find in useful in future. You can check supported mime type in following way:

`MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().hasMimeType(mimeType)`